# error on trying to insert Opportunity Contact Role

Tags: rest-api, rest

I'm getting this error when trying to create an Opportunity Contact Role via the REST API:

`CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: entity type cannot be inserted: Opportunity Contact Role`

I suspect this is due to a missing permission somewhere, because it works okay when using a different User, in a sandbox.

If I go to Administration -> Users -> Profiles -> [my custom profile] -> Object Settings -> OpportunityContact Role, it shows that I have the same set of permissions as the other User (which is able to create Opportunity Contact Roles):

```
| Field Name       | Read Access | Edit Access |
|------------------|-------------|-------------|
| Contact          | ✓           | ✓           |
| Created By       | ✓           |             |
| Last Modified By | ✓           |             |
| Opportunity      | ✓           | ✓           |
| Primary          | ✓           | ✓           |
| Role             | ✓           | ✓           |
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: Are Opportunity Contact Roles enabled (see Sales Settings)? That's about the only thing I could think of.

Comment: Yes, they are enabled.

Comment: if you try and add the OCR in the UI, what error do you get?  Do you even see the New button?

Comment: This is an API only user so I don't have access to the UI